# node.js + mongodb: wait for query to complete

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a simple code in node.js

```
async function dbQuery() {
        const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient; 
        const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/"; 
        const db = await MongoClient.connect(url);
        const dbo = db.db("mydb");
        const result = await dbo.collection("tblData").find({}).toArray()
        return result;
    }

async function doIt() {
        try {
              const res = await dbQuery();
              console.log("Records: " + res.length);
            } catch (error) {
              console.log(error);
            }
   }
//
console.log("Starting...")
doIt()
console.log("Done!")
```

the output is:

```
Starting...
Done!
Records: 24
```

how to force the code to wait for the query to finish? to have the output like:

```
Starting...
Records: 24
Done!
```

Comment: It's because 'doIt()' is async. What exactly do u need?

Comment: As per your code, the execution is right. But if you want to perform some other actions then you need to write code in that way. this is not your complete code better to provide the case why you want to wait for just `console.log('Done!')`?

Comment: `await doIt()`. Using `await` "inside" functions does not magically make the Promise "go away". It's still a Promise and `await` is just "sugar" to resolve it Just think of logically writing `then()` in place of every `await` and "then" ( yes "pun" ) it should be clear to you.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer says use Promises, but I don't think that would be necessary, you are using `async` and `await`, a more up to date implementation of Promises.

Just move the `doIt()` function call into an async call. Since this is node, and is non blocking, this would be a more correct implementation.

```
async function dbQuery() {
    const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient; 
    const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/"; 
    const db = await MongoClient.connect(url);
    const dbo = db.db("mydb");
    const result = await dbo.collection("tblData").find({}).toArray()
    return result;
}

async function doIt() {
    console.log("Starting...");
    try {
        const res = await dbQuery();
        console.log("Records: " + res.length);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    console.log("Done!");
}

doIt();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use promises to do the job.

```
async function doIt() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
          const res = await dbQuery();
          console.log("Records: " + res.length);
          resolve();
        } catch (error) {
          reject(error);
        }
  });
}

console.log("Starting...")
doIt().then(() => {
   console.log("Done!");
})
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to call your doIt() function by await and its working..

```
something...
await doit();
something...
```